# Best Way to Join One Column on Columns From Two Other Tables

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I have a schema like the following in Oracle

Section:

```
+--------+----------+
| sec_ID | group_ID |
+--------+----------+
|    1   |     1    |
|    2   |     1    |
|    3   |     2    |
|    4   |     2    |
+--------+----------+
```

Section_to_Item:

```
+--------+---------+
| sec_ID | item_ID |
+--------+---------+
|    1   |     1   |
|    1   |     2   |
|    2   |     3   |
|    2   |     4   |
+--------+---------+
```

Item:

```
+---------+------+
| item_ID | data |
+---------+------+
|    1    |  a   |
|    2    |  b   |
|    3    |  c   |
|    4    |  d   |
+---------+------+
```

Item_Version:

```
+---------+----------+--------+
| item_ID | start_ID | end_ID |
+---------+----------+--------+
|    1    |    1     |        |
|    2    |    1     |    3   |
|    3    |    2     |        |
|    4    |    1     |    2   |
+---------+----------+--------+
```

Section_to_Item has FK into Section and Item on the *_ID columns.
Item_version is indexed on item_ID but has no FK to Item.item_ID (ran out of space in the snapshot group).

I have code that receives a list of version IDs and I want to get all items in sections in a given group that are valid for at least one of the versions passed in. If an item has no end_ID, it's valid for anything starting with start_ID. If it has an end_id, it's valid for anything up until (not including) end_ID.

What I currently have is:

```
SELECT Items.data
FROM Section, Section_to_Items, Item, Item_Version
WHERE Section.group_ID = 1
AND Section_to_Item.sec_ID = Section.sec_ID
AND Item.item_ID = Section_to_Item.item_ID
AND Item.item_ID = Item_Version.item_ID
AND exists (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT 2 AS version FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS version FROM DUAL
    ) passed_versions
    WHERE Item_Version.start_ID <= passed_versions.version
    AND (Item_Version.end_ID IS NULL or Item_Version.end_ID > passed_version.version)
)
```

Note that the UNION ALL statement is dynamically generated from the list of passed in versions.

This query currently does a cartesian join and is very slow.
For some reason, if I change the query to join

```
AND Item_Version.item_ID = Section_to_Item.item_ID
```

which is not a FK, the query does not do the cartesian join and is much faster.

A) Can anyone explain why this is?
B) Is this the right way to be joining this sequence of tables (I feel weird about joining Item.item_ID to two different tables)
C) Is this the right way to get versions between start_ID and end_ID?

#### Edit

Same query with inner join syntax:

```
SELECT Items.data
FROM Item
INNER JOIN Section_to_Items ON Section_to_Items.item_ID = Item.item_ID
INNER JOIN Section ON Section.sec_ID = Section_to_Items.sec_ID
INNER JOIN Item_Version ON Item_Version.item_ID = Item_.item_ID
WHERE Section.group_ID = 1
AND exists (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT 2 AS version FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS version FROM DUAL
    ) passed_versions
    WHERE Item_Version.start_ID <= passed_versions.version
    AND (Item_Version.end_ID IS NULL or Item_Version.end_ID > passed_version.version)
)
```

Note that in this case the performance difference comes from joining on Item_Version first and then joining Section_to_Item on Item_Version.item_ID.

In terms of table size, Section_to_Item, Item, and Item_Version should be similar (1000s) while Section should be small.

#### Edit

I just found out that apparently, the schema has no FKs. The FKs specified in the schema configuration files are ignored. They're just there for documentation. So there's no difference between joining on a FK column or not. That being said, by changing the joins into a cascade of SELECT INs, I'm able to avoid joining the entire Item table twice. I don't love the resulting query, and I don't really understand the difference, but the stats indicate it's much less work (changes the A-Rows returned from the inner most scan on Section from 656,000 to 488 (it used to be 656k starts returning 1 row, now it's 488 starts returning 1 row)).

#### Edit

It turned out to be stale statistics - the two queries were equivalent the whole time but with the incomplete statistics, the DB happened to notice the correct plan only in the second instance. After updating statistics, both queries generated the same plan.

Comment: Learn to use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  This may fix your problem and it certainly makes it easier for others to figure out what might be going wrong.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Both queries are optimized into the same plan by Oracle, but if it makes it easier for you to read, I updated the post.

Comment: It sounds like you already have a solution, just one that you aren't happy with because you don't understand why it works?  I'm assuming that you are already aware that creating a FK constraint doesn't automatically also create an index?  I totally agree that the "fix" you found isn't great, as you are basically adding a redundant `JOIN` (or a redundant `JOIN` condition depending on which version of the SQL you use).  I would assume that this is acting more like a database hint in this case?  Are your statistics up to date/ automatically being generated?

Comment: Answering your third question, is this the right way to constrain the versions being returned?  I don't particularly like your solution, where you use a sub query to generate what seems like a hardcoded list of versions.  Is this list likely to change often?  Will it actually come from a database table in real life?  If not then why not just take out your `UNION` sub query, and simply add `Item_Version.start_ID <= 3
    AND (Item_Version.end_ID IS NULL or Item_Version.end_ID > 2)` to your `WHERE` clause?  I could be missing the point here?

Comment: @RichardHansell yes the query works, I was just wondering if there is a better way to structure it. This doesn't seem like it should be a hard/slow thing, but it is and I don't know why. I didn't know if there was a way to not join the same column on two different tables or a different way to do the UNION ALL thing.

Comment: @RichardHansell In response to the hard coded versions: Those are passed in to the function that generates the query. And they could be a large list of numbers. We just want do know, for each item, if the item has a start_ID and end_ID pair that surrounds any one of those. Note too that the Item_Version table can have multiple rows for an item_ID if the item_ID was started and then ended and then started again, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best idea but this seems to avoid the cartesian join:

```
select data
from Item
where item_ID in (
    select item_ID
    from Item_Version
    where item_ID in (
        select item_ID
        from Section_to_Item
        where sec_ID in (
            select sec_ID
            from Section
            where group_ID = 1
        )
    )
    and exists (
        select 1
        from (
            select 2 as version
            from dual
            union all
            select 3 as version
            from dual
        ) versions
        where versions.version >= start_ID
        and (end_ID is null or versions.version <)
    )
)
```

Comment: This was a red herring - with updated DB statistics this did not improve query performance